# Estimate the relative intensities of absorption given the split in energy levels

Tags: spectroscopy, ir-spectroscopy, uv-vis-spectroscopy

> Estimate the relative intensities at $\pu{25 °C}$ of absorption originated in the ground state and the first excited state when the energy levels involved are separated by:
>
> (a) $\pu{10000 cm^-1};$
> (b) $\pu{1000 cm^-1};$
> (c) $\pu{10 cm^-1}.$

Here, the given numbers are the wave numbers of the EM radiation.

I have a problem understanding the term “*relative intensities*”. What does it imply? My professor has told me to calculate it using the population of states using the formula:

$$\frac{N'}{N} = \exp\left(\frac{-\Delta E}{k_\mathrm B T}\right)$$

But my problem is that the term $N'/N$ is the ratio of the number of particles in excited state and the ground state. How does it relate to relative intensities?

I'm fairly new to spectroscopy so I might have used few terms in the wrong fashion.

Comment: The relative intensities are proportional to the number of particules. So try to calculate N'/N for the three values of energy levels. You will immediately obtain the result your teacher would like you to get.

Comment: @Maurice Thanks for help. Can you give some text where this concept is described in detail? Hope you don't mind.

Comment: You don't need a textbook. You have the formula. Only thing to do is transform the unit $cm^{-1}$ in frequency unit (Hertz), then in energy unit (Joule), and divide the result by $kT$, where $ k$ is Boltzmann constant. Hopefully you know the corresponding numerical values.

Comment: @Optimus _IF_ truly needed, see textbooks about physical chemistry, because Boltzmann constant and distribution (statistical thermodynamics) / [Boltzmann statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_statistics). Nuclear Magnetic Resonance spectrosccopy (NMR) and optical pumping of LASERs seek to go beyond what _heat taken alone_ would offer ([population inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Population_inversion)).  Note however, this detail of understanding may be required only if you study e.g., chemistry, but is presented to you typically in or even past year three.

Comment: Do you know the equation $E = h\nu = \frac{hc}{\lambda}$?

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne yes ofc. Every one studies it in high school.